# Magento 2: Return value based on availability date and current date

Tags: magento2.3

I m trying to achieve the value based on following logic to use the code in Module called Advanced product feeds. They allow to create dynamic variable to use in feed.

I have attribute in magento 2 called availability_date, it contain future date of product that will be released on that date but can be pre-ordered.

What i want is to check the availability date against current date and return the value based on that login. Here is code i am trying to work on

$availibility_date = [];
foreach ($product->getAvailibilityDate() ?: [] as $availibility_date) {
$availibility_dates[] = $availibility_date->getAvailibilityDate();
}
echo implode(', ', $availibility_date);

It does only return id of product, but not returning the date.

Comment: If I correct understand used extension you should use `return` instead of `echo`. Also you can use right area to validate result for any items.

Comment: can you describe a bit more ?